# Audio not working on Windows 8

Tags: windows

A laptopt
Conexant HD Smart Audio 221 is enabled and the sound meter is moving as if audio was working fine but no there is no audio playback. Also, YouTube video's play in slow-motion. On Spotify the progress bar moves (although slow) but no audio. This only happens after the notebook comes out of sleep-mode.

I have reinstalled the drivers and even tried to run them in windows 7 compatibility mode but still no audio. I couldn't find any newer drivers, and manufacturer gave me zero support.
I think that it's related to the Conexant drivers, or the Mobile Intel 4 Series Express Chipset Family drivers.

please help me! thank you in advance

Comment: Upgraded from windows Vista 32 bit to Windows 8 Pro **64 bit?** Could that be the issue?

Comment: If you have a 32 bit bus on your motherboard, you cannot upgrade to a 64 bit system and even if you do get it to upgrade, it will not perform properly and I suspect that this is the case here.

Comment: Read this http://superuser.com/a/446407/181734

Answer (score 1):

In control panel\device manager, right click your audio device, go to properties and check to see if it has a power management tab. If it does, make sure 'Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power' is unticked.

Comment: Hmm, ok... You can try setting your laptop to high performance by selecting it from power options. This will make the laptop maximize performance at the cost of power. This should keep more devices active after sleep and may solve the slow playback issue.